# Try is working properly but catch is given error

Tags: android, try-catch, android-volley

Hey guys i am working in an app and i am verify my mobile number through `OTP` when i am send `OTP` to verify there is error mobile is verify but `catch` block is given error and `Activity` not going to next `Acivity` and not log is showing

```
 private void verifyOtp(final String otp){
    final StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            config.Config.URL_VERIFY_OTP, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
                // Parsing json object response
                // response will be a json object
                boolean status =responseObj.getBoolean("status");
                if (status==true) {
                    // parsing the user profile information
                    JSONObject profileObj = responseObj.getJSONObject(response);
                    String mobile = profileObj.getString("mobile");
                    PrefManager pref = new PrefManager(getApplicationContext());
                    pref.createLogin(mobile);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HttpService.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTPIF"+status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTPELSE"+status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {  //------this is working and give toast----//
                System.out.print("jsonError :=>"+e);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error is WWW: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "HTTPError: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        MyApplication userinfo = (MyApplication)getApplicationContext();
        final  String user = userinfo.getuser();      // Global Variable get Value uID
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("akey","xxxxxxxxxx");
            params.put("mobileverify", otp);
            params.put("uid",user);
            Log.e(TAG, "Posting params: " + params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String mobile = profileObj.getString("mobile");
```

You may get no String but a null.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `JSONException`. This may be due to many reasons and you will find them here: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html

The reason for this is, you are using a `StringRequest`. That means, the `response` is a plain `String` and not a `JSON` response. Just print out the `reponse` and see for yourself that it's not a valid `JSON`.  What you need to use instead is a `JSONRequest`, or handle the `String` reponse as it is, instead of json parsing.

**UPDATE:**
Your problem might be because of either of the two lines below, since both of them can throw `JSONException`: [getJSONObject()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String)) , [getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String))

```
JSONObject profileObj = responseObj.getJSONObject(response);
String mobile = profileObj.getString("mobile");
```

You say your JSON response is `{"msg":"verified","status":true}`. Then how are you trying to fetch `profileObj` or the value for `mobile` ? If the value is not found for the key, it will throw `JSONException`. To avoid this, you need check if the value for the key exists. Use [has(String key)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)) to confirm a mapping for the key exists, before fetching it.

Comment: this my responce json `{"msg":"verified","status":true}`  it is valid but its given error

Comment: Post the `JSONException`: `System.out.print("jsonError :=>"+e);`

Comment: this is error
`Error Is...org.json.JSONException: No value for {"msg":"verified","status":true}`